# Assigning ScrollViewer to just a Grid within a Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, scrollviewer

I have 3 Grids - 1 master grid that houses 2 child grids. I want ScrollViewer to appear in just 1 of the child grids. How can this be done? The ScrollViewer either doesn't show up (when set to auto), or it shows up but is disabled with no position indicator (when set to visible).
I'm able to apply it to the master grid and it works, but not the child grid. All heights are set to auto in the case of master grid, so I assume the same settings will work for child grid as well, but it didn't. Here are the extracts of my codes currently:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StoreMgmtSys.Views.IssueInfoPage" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
  <Grid x:Name="layoutGridMaster" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ShowGridLines="False">
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <Grid x:Name="gridEqpItem" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
      </Grid>       
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="layoutGridIssue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Edit - Appendix for people who wants to know the content of my grid with the ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="gridEqpItem" Background="PaleVioletRed" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="2,2,2,0"
                                 x:Name="gridCommsEqp" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" MaxHeight="500"
                                 ColumnWidth="Auto" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="True"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="556"
                                 IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="gridCommsEqp_OnSelectionChanged"
                                 Width="Auto" ShowGroupPanel="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 FilteringMode="FilterRow" FilterOperatorsLoading="Grid_OnFilterOperatorsLoading">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding CommonDesc}" UniqueName="CommonDesc"
                                                TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="190" TextAlignment="Center">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Equipment" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding OtherKeywords}"
                                                UniqueName="OtherKeywords"
                                                TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="210" TextAlignment="Center">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Keywords" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding CurrentQty}" MaxWidth="73"
                                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                                UniqueName="CurrentQty" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Current Quantity" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding TotalQty}" TextAlignment="Center"
                                                UniqueName="TotalQty" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="73">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Total Quantity" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
            <telerik:RadListBox Margin="5,5,5,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                x:Name="listBoxItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Width="250" SelectionMode="Multiple" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                TextPath="Serial" MaxHeight="400" Background="Transparent"
                                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MetroListBoxItem}"
                                SelectionChanged="ListBoxItems_OnSelectionChanged">
                <telerik:RadListBox.DragVisualProvider>
                    <telerik:ScreenshotDragVisualProvider />
                </telerik:RadListBox.DragVisualProvider>
                <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
                    <telerik:ListBoxDragDropBehavior />
                </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
                <telerik:RadListBox.DataConverter>
                    <storeMgmtSys:ItemToIssueConverter />
                </telerik:RadListBox.DataConverter>
                <telerik:RadListBox.AllowDrop>False</telerik:RadListBox.AllowDrop>
            </telerik:RadListBox>
            <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,5,0"
                                 FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"
                                 x:Name="gridCommsEqpSet" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" MaxHeight="400"
                                 Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 ColumnWidth="Auto" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="True"
                                 MaxWidth="300" Width="Auto" ShowGroupPanel="False" SelectionMode="Single"
                                 RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 SelectionChanged="GridCommsEqpSet_OnSelectionChanged"
                                 FilterOperatorsLoading="Grid_OnFilterOperatorsLoading">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" UniqueName="Description"
                                                TextWrapping="Wrap" Header="SELECT A SET" Width="Auto"
                                                MaxWidth="200" HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                                                IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
            <telerik:RadListBox Margin="0,5,5,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                                x:Name="listBoxSetItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Width="250" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MetroListBoxItem}"
                                SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="Transparent"                                    
                                TextPath="Serial" MaxHeight="400" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <telerik:RadListBox.DragVisualProvider>
                    <telerik:ScreenshotDragVisualProvider />
                </telerik:RadListBox.DragVisualProvider>
                <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
                    <telerik:ListBoxDragDropBehavior />
                </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
                <telerik:RadListBox.DataConverter>
                    <storeMgmtSys:ItemToIssueConverter />
                </telerik:RadListBox.DataConverter>
                <telerik:RadListBox.AllowDrop>False</telerik:RadListBox.AllowDrop>
            </telerik:RadListBox>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Content="Issue Date" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF008BFF" FontSize="14" />
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,0,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Content="Receipt Date" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF008BFF" FontSize="14" />
            <telerik:RadDatePicker Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="98,5,0,0"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   x:Name="issueDate" Height="30" Width="155"
                                   SelectionChanged="issueDate_SelectionChanged" />
            <telerik:RadDatePicker Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="98,0,0,0"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   x:Name="receiptDate" Height="30" Width="155"
                                   SelectionChanged="receiptDate_SelectionChanged"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: you need to have enough content so that scroll-viewer can actually scroll.

Comment: I have enough contents. This is just an extract of it. As mentioned, setting it to the master grid works.

Comment: could you also post some sample contents? btw setting the Grid's Height as `Height="2000"` or any number above the available size will enable the scrolling

Comment: I have no idea at all what you are concerned about. If trying it on the master grid works, it means it has enough content and size. What my contents are exactly don't even matter. Even if my controls aren't telerik, I don't see what there is for you to be able to truly test out since all the stuffs are binding. Do you even know what you are commenting on anyways? I have flagged your comment as unconstructive, especially since I have reiterate enough times on the master grid scenario.

Comment: thank you for the flags, I appreciate your effort to read the same. However as a last resort I would ask you to remove `Height="Auto"` from all of the controls in the hierarchy upwards i.e. user control and master grid. and any other controls on top of it. or define a MaxHeight on layoutGridMaster

Comment: Thank you for further efforts in assisting. Nothing is working unfortunately. I have tried playing with values of MaxHeight and Height to smaller values, but they only cut away my controls and the ScrollViewer still don't show up. If it do work, it would be confusing also since 'Auto' works when it comes to the master grid. Now I'm wondering if there's such thing as scrollviewer to a child grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem. The problem lies with the RowDefinition of my master grid (I did not reveal the codes in my question). The trick is to set the first RowDefinition Height to "*" as shown below. Initially my code was "Auto". Don't ask me why though; I don't know how to explain well as my programming concepts are not so good yet.

```
<Grid x:Name="layoutGridMaster" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ShowGridLines="False">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  .
  .
  .
</Grid>
```